# Minikube: Are there any ways for driver=none to use ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I am using Minikube on my laptop with "driver=none" option. When I try to enable ingress, I got the following error:

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress

❌  Exiting due to MK_USAGE: Due to networking limitations of driver none, ingress addon is not supported. Try using a different driver.
```

After some googling, I found that Ingress addon stopped to work with 'none' VM driver starting from Minikube v1.12.x, and I am using v1.13.1. (please refer to: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9322)

I wonder whether there are other ways to install "native" ingress on Minikube with the "driver=none" option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

Unfortunately, as you already found out, this addon is not supported with with `vm-driver=none`.

If you use the `none` driver, some Kubernetes components run as privileged containers that have side effects outside of the Minikube environment. Those side effects mean that the `none` driver is not recommended for personal workstations.

Also, according to [the official docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/):

> Most users of this driver should consider the newer [Docker
> driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/), as it is significantly easier to configure and does not
> require root access. The ‘none’ driver is recommended for advanced
> users only.

So basically you have two options here:

- downgrade to Minikube v1.11 (not recommended)
- use a supported driver (strongly recommended)

Remember that these changes are made for a reason and going against them is usually a bad idea. It would be better to follow the official recommendation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I had tried to downgrade to v1.12.2, I was able to enable the Ingress addon, but when I tried to use Traefik as ingress control, I ran into other problems.

The reason why I stick to "driver=none" (for my development environment) is I originally used docker-swarm, and have docker images locally, using "driver=none" saves the time of pulling all the docker images from the remote docker registry.

As for now, maybe I will give up the plan of using Minikube on the development environment.