# Kubernetes ingress address is empty

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-cluster

I have set up a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube in an Ubuntu VM. I cloned this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cloudxlab/minikube-static-app/tree/main/k8s) and created the namespace, deployment, service and ingress.

I have also enabled ingress addon by running  `minikube addons enable ingress`.

When I run `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx`, the external ip is none.

When I run `kubectl get ingress -n sample`, the address is empty.

Please advise how to set up k8s ingress.

PS: I had minikube tunnel running.

PS 2: `kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE

ingress-nginx-admission-create--1-*     0/1     Completed   0          11m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch--1-*      0/1     Completed   1          11m
ingress-nginx-controller-*              1/1     Running     0          11m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289478/minikube-are-there-any-ways-for-driver-none-to-use-ingress/64315071). It worked after I downgraded Minikube to v1.11.0. I used --driver=none.